# How do I stop CouchDB from running on startup?

Tags: database, couchdb

I installed CouchDB on Windows7 a while back to try it out. But it's always running on port 5984 on startup. How do I stop this?

**Edit:** Nevermind I found an uninstaller!

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable the Windows Service for Apache CouchDB. If you'd prefer to just run it when you need it.